# Working with graphson result in Cosmos DB

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I am working with the result of cosmos db query by passing to constructor of a class:

```
public Session GetASession()
{
    IDocumentQuery<dynamic> query = database.Client.CreateGremlinQuery<dynamic>(database.Graph, $"g.V()");
    var session = new Data(query.ExecuteNextAsync().Result.FirstOrDefault());
    return session;
}
```

Which `Session` class is implemented likes the following:

```
public Class Session
{
    dynamic graphson;
    public Session(dynamic graphson)
    {
        this.graphson = graphson;
    }
    public string Id
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)graphson.id;
        }
        set
        {
            graphson.id = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is when calling `GetASession` function, although the query get some session from db, but `Id` in returned session in not available and get error in this way. Hence, the question is where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found returned object from the query is weak reference object, so if we not assign it to a variable, it will be disposed. Hence, the solution is:

```
public Session GetASession()
{
    IDocumentQuery<dynamic> query = database.Client.CreateGremlinQuery<dynamic>(database.Graph, $"g.V()");
    var result = query.ExecuteNextAsync().Result.FirstOrDefault();
    var session = new Data(result); // this solves the problem
    return session;
}
```